# How to select sum if the field has a value of either 0 or 1?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, web

I want to sum the field when my column `is_active` is `0` and I want to show it to my dashboard page. If `is_active` is `1` it should skip and not sum.

How to do this? What's the query? I have my example query I built in `CodeIgniter`:

```
$this->db->select_sum('is_active');
    $query = $this->db->get('postfes');
    if ($query->num_rows() = 0) {
        return $query->num_rows()->is_active;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: which column you need to use for sum ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `where` condition

```
$this->db->select_sum('is_active'); // the field you want to sum
$this->db->where('is_active', 0)
$data = $this->db->get('postfes')->row();
if ($data) {
    return $data->is_active;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to count where is_active = 0 then use

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as total'); // the field you want to sum
    $this->db->where('is_active', 0)
    $data = $this->db->get('postfes')->row();
    if ($data) {
        return $data->total;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: i forgot how to use 'where' condition lol, it show but why just one ?, in my filed i have 3 is_active = 0

Comment: you mean u need to count total number where   is_active is 0 ?